# docker mount on windows, directory is empty

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Running a simple docker test.

```
docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls -al /data
```

Results in the following output.

```
total 4
drwxr-xr-x    2 root     root            40 Oct 19 09:02 .
drwxr-xr-x    1 root     root          4096 Oct 19 09:05 ..
```

the directory is empty, in windows it contains the user(s).

**edit**

Further to this, looking at the docker log file, I see this:

```
[11:11:02.873][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Creating share "C:\" as "C" with Full Control to "QXV0615"
[11:11:02.957][Cmd            ][Info   ] C was shared successfully.
[11:11:03.005][Cmd            ][Info   ] Share name        C
[11:11:03.005][Cmd            ][Info   ] Path              C:\
[11:11:03.005][Cmd            ][Info   ] Remark            
[11:11:03.005][Cmd            ][Info   ] Maximum users     No limit
[11:11:03.005][Cmd            ][Info   ] Users             
[11:11:03.005][Cmd            ][Info   ] Caching           Caching disabled
[11:11:03.006][Cmd            ][Info   ] Permission        W9\QXV0615, FULL
[11:11:03.006][Cmd            ][Info   ] The command completed successfully.
[11:11:03.009][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "C" is shared
[11:11:03.011][SambaShare     ][Error  ] Unable to validate cred: Invalid username or password
[11:11:03.011][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Removing share C
[11:11:03.053][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Mount
```

seems there is a samba credentials issue? How do I fix the credentials?

Comment: Directory separators in windows are backslashes. Please try this: `-v c:\Users:/data`

Comment: I get exactly the same result, backslash or forward slash - something is wrong with the docker installation or the network, and i need some help trying to figure out the root cause.

Comment: It might be a permission problem. What happens when you mount a folder in your home directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**VPN ISSUE**

The problem occurs when my CISCO VPN is connected.
Volumes will not work when the VPN is connected. I have tried the suggestions here, but no dice!

https://github.com/boot2docker/boot2docker/issues/628
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/360